# Given Darboux integrable functions $f, g: [a,b] \rightarrow [0, \infty)$, show that $f + 3g$ is Darboux integrable.

Tags: real-analysis

Here is what I have so far:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be ABF. There exist partitions $P_f, P_g$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(f, P_f) - L(f, P_f) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $U(g, P_g) - L(g, P_g)< \frac{\varepsilon}{6}$. Let $P = P_f \cup P_g$. Then $U(f + 3g, P) - L(f + 3g, P) \leq (U(f, P) + U(3g, P)) - (L(f, P) + L(3g, P))$.

I want to show that this inequality is less than $\frac{\varepsilon}{2} + 3\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{6} = \varepsilon$, but I am not sure how to deal with $U(3g, P)$ and $L(3g, P)$. Is it the case that $U(3g, P) - L(3g, P) \leq 3(U(g, P_g) - L(g, P_g))$?